# Testing CakePhp3 plugin -> Error loading plugin / missing class

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, helper

Actually working on a Bootstrap 3 plugin, everythinks works now. I want to test everything developping test with php Unit !

But when i call php unit it say that he don't found the class like that :

> Fatal error : Class 'BsHelpers\View\Helper\BsHelper' not found in C:\wamp3\www\wac_lucien\BsHelpers\BsHelpersCakePHP3\3.2\plugins\BsHelpers\tests\TestCase\View\Helper\BsHelpersTest.php on line 26

So after trying to follow exactly the documentation from CakePHP3 i meet the problem at the begenning. For now I only got that :

```
<?php
namespace BsHelpers\Test\TestCase\View\Helper;

use BsHelpers\View\Helper\BsHelper;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;
use Cake\View\View;

class BsHelperTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->View = new View();
        $this->Bs = new BsHelper($this->View);
    }

    public function testBar()
    {

    }
}
```

I think problem can be in bootstrap.php. The path of the plugin loader can be false but i don't know how to set up...

```
Plugin::load('BsHelpers', ['path' => ROOT . DS]);
```

In the composer.json of my plugin i got :

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "BsHelpers\\": "./plugins/BsHelpers/src",
        "BsHelpers\\Test\\": "./plugins/BsHelpers/tests"
    }
},
```

I invoke php unit test doing ( in my plugin folder )

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```

And my phpunit.xml.dist looks like

```
<phpunit
colors="true"
stopOnFailure="false"
bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="BsHelpers Test Cases">
        <directory>./tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">./src/</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Any idea of why i can't acces my Helper during running my test ?

Pls guys I really need ideas

Comment: Sounds more like your autoload configuration (`composer.json`) is incorrect, or you're not using the proper composer autoloader from the plugins vendor folder. Without additional info on the mentioned possible problems, and some details on how you actually run the tests/invoke phpunit, it's pretty much impossible for anyone to do anything other than guessing.

Comment: Ok sorry for forgot some informations ! I will add that to the initial question !

Comment: That file looks weird, it looks more like an application level composer file, not one of a plugin!? Are you developing a standalone plugin, or is it part of an application? Also how/where are you loading the autoloader (`vendor/autoload.php`)?

Comment: It's an independant plugin ! And the autoload is loaded in the composer.json of my plugin like that "require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';"

Comment: "_the autoload is loaded in the composer.json of my plugin_" probably a language issue, but that doesn't make too much sense, the PHP snippet for sure isn't located in the `composer.json` file. Given that you are developing a standalone plugin, the paths `./plugins/BsHelpers/...` seem wrong to me. The composer file should be in the plugins root, that is one level above the `src` folder, and consequently the path for the namespaces should be `src` and `tests` (where the tests config should be in `autoload-dev`), and the `App` namespace should point to a test app if at all.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I tried again running tests. I found the error and change the line, but I don't understand why that was giving issues in tests.

Initialy I tried to understand CakePHP3 plugins, by working with [this plugin from friendsofcake](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui), when i made my plugin (to insert more functionalities) I just copied the composer.json to see the result with my plugin. Just forget to change that part.

So error was in the composer.json of the plugin :

```
{
"name": "friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui",
"description": "Twitter Bootstrap 3 support for CakePHP 3",
"type": "cakephp-plugin"
}
```

I changed the name line with

```
"name": "lucienleroux/bs-helpers",
```

And I really don't understand why that solved the problem because nowhere I am setting a name like "lucienleroux/bs-helpers" in my plugin. And in fact it works with any other string like "test/bs_helpers" ... If you understand I am interested in the answer !